# how to alert colspan value on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Dynamic table here, i need to alert the colspan value of clicked table cell. How can i make it possible

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td></td>
<td colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="1"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: guess you have got the answers needed, just one small correction, please close the `</tr>` tag in the `thead` properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('body').on('click','td',function(){
  if($(this).hasAttr('colspan'))
   alert($(this).attr('colspan'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('colspan'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
  alert($(this).attr('colspan'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic elements we use delegation, Because the table is dynamic, you have to handle event like bellow.

```
$(document).on('click', 'td',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('colspan'))
});
```

If a `td` will have colspan it will alert it's value, otherwise it'll alert `undefined`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/90/)

BTW My demo has an static table

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').on('click', 'td[colspan]', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('colspan'));
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L03LLucx/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this .... Cick here for js [FIDDLE/Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/f4swh6vr/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").on('click','td[colspan]',function()
                  {
                      console.log($(this));
                      var colspan_val = $(this).attr('colspan');
                      console.log(colspan_val);

                      alert('this is colspan');
                      alert('colspan value: '+colspan_val);

                  })
})
```